# Set background image not from drawable folder

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to set a background image but not from drawable folder, the image is from gallery which is internal storage.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Why not? Get a `Bitmap` object if you know its path, then create a `BitmapDrawable` out of the bitmap and there you have it.

Comment: +1 gunar, Get you image from gallery as a bitmap and display that bitmap in imageview

Comment: how to create BitmapDrawable ?

Comment: I can get image from gallery and display in imageview, the question is the image has to display on custom view. I use setBackgroundResource is not work.

Comment: please check my updated answer to get solution for your prob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this from Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

You may open Gallery intent from Activity and also handle OnActicityResult method ..... [Try This link for solution](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/)

So, now for setBackground you can convert bitmap to drawable using below code..

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
view.setBackground(d);
```

I hope this may help you...

Answer (score 0):

Get you image from gallery as a bitmap and display that bitmap in imageview
This is a very nice [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/) on showing image from gallery in ImageView.